# Dynamic facts to drools guvnor

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I'm trying to integrate the Guvnor standalone rule editor to an existing application. The application now allows drl files to be uploaded. I'm looking to integrate the Guvnor editor so that user can create or edit rules from the application. The problem i'm facing is, the application allows user to enter the fields for rules and are stored in db. The fields are retrieved on runtime. There is no model class available. I couldn't figure out whether I can use these fields to dynamically populate the facts shown in the Guvnor editor.

Any help is greatly appreciated..Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Drools rules work by matching on facts, which are just Java classes. Java is not a dynamic language, so you can't just add methods to classes. Therefore you need to do something different.

The simplest solution would be to have a base fact which contains a HashMap of key/value pairs. Rules could then be written to match on values in that collection. The shortcoming here would be that the engine would not react to changes to those values.

For truly dynamic facts, it wouldn't be difficult to generate DRL code for declarative facts based on the user models. You could then load these into the knowledge base and write rules based on them.